# Reading Test from browser

Tags: php, mysql, linux, nginx

I got an HTTP ERROR 500  whiles attempting to run this code in Nginx. My aim is to read test_parameter from the test database and print it on screen in the browser. I can't figure out what is wrong and any help will be appreciated, thank you

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "test_user", "t3$tp@ss", "testdb", 3306);
if ($conn) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM test_table";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
     echo "ID: " . $row["id"] . " VALUE: " . $row["test_parameter"];
  }
  else {
    echo "No rows to display";
}
else {
    echo "Could not connect to MySQL";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error is a generic error message informing you that the server crashed while processing the request. Beyond that, it's (intentionally) meaningless, and is of very little use for debugging. You need to check the error logs on the server to try and find the underlying exception message. Once you've got that, you stand a chance of identifying the problem.

Comment: Maybe use single quotes for your password, `'t3$tp@ss'` instead of `"t3$tp@ss"`, so PHP doesn't try to expand a variable that's not defined

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: You forgot to close curled bracket https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/a9bf483591999188ffd9d5672b6eadba/php/php81/92773706774660fa9734cf6f310e6b5d/

Comment: Thank you very much that was it, but now it echos cannot connect to database

Comment: `echo mysqli_connect_error();` to find out why it can't connect